# Print a right-angled triangle with certain condition in c

Tags: c, for-loop, geometry, conditional-statements

Enter a certain number, and that number is a condition which determines the number of chars in a single row.Let's say the number is 3
In the first row there is only 1 char.
In second row there is a condition. `a+1` Where a is the number that we entered
In third row is `2a+1`
Fourth `3a+1`
And so on...
Example:
Number that we entered is 3.

```
a (1)
aaaa (3+1)
aaaaaaa (2*3+1)
```

Here is what i've came up. I have trouble with implementing that condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,n;

printf("Enter the numbers of rows:");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
printf("a");
printf("\n");
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: What is the question you are asking because right now it looks like you are asking us to troubleshoot your code for you.

Comment: How can i implement the condition (a+1) , (2a+1) into the code i've posted?

Answer (score 0):

Just start iterating inner `for` loop starting from `n` till `i * n` as below,

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=n;j<=i*n;j++)
  printf("a");
  printf("\n");
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/hN1xNd)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: get used to start counting at 0

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) // could be for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
for(j=1;j<=i;j++) // could be for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

---

You have to have a multiplication by 3 "somewhere". Try and find the right place and what to multiply by 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n*i+1;j++)
        printf("a");
    printf("\n");
}
```